# How to animate a labels position in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation

I have just a simple label:

[image]

So far here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


@IBAction func onTap(_ sender: Any) {


}
```

When I click the tapGesture I want the label to animate its position to the bottom of the screen and then then when I click again animate to the center. Basically just toggling back and fourth. In my Xcode project I'm adding a slide up menu but having some trouble because I haven't really done anything with interface in swift. Answering this would put me on the right track I think.

Comment: Have you add any constraints on this label ?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "My Label"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 24)
        return label
    }()
    
    private var labelIsDown = false
    
    private var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var centerYConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    private var centerXConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToTap))
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        label.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        
        setupLabelConstraints()
    }
    
    private func setupLabelConstraints() {
        bottomConstraint = label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor)
        centerYConstraint = label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        centerXConstraint = label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor)
        
        centerXConstraint.isActive = true
        centerYConstraint.isActive = true
    }
    
    @objc private func respondToTap() {
        if labelIsDown {
            bottomConstraint.isActive = false
            centerYConstraint.isActive = true
        } else {
            centerYConstraint.isActive = false
            bottomConstraint.isActive = true
        }
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (_) in
            self.labelIsDown.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

So the keypoint here is to setup constraints and then animate the changes of them...
If you want to get the same result for a storyboard based project, I assume you will have to create outlets for your constraints...